# Variance and using Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability-theory, variance

I have $X_1,X_2,\dots$ independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, with
$$S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(X_k),\qquad S=\int_0^1fdx$$
and $f$ Borel measurable on $[0,1]$ and integrable, and $\int_0^1f(x)^2dx<\infty$. I want to use Chebyshev's inequality to estimate
$$P(|S_n-S|>\alpha n^\frac{-1}{2})$$.

I have shown that $S_n$ converges to $S$, and I know that by Chebyshev's inequality
$$P(|S_n-S|>\alpha n^\frac{-1}{2})\leq\frac{E(S_n-S)^2}{\alpha n^{-1}}$$
I'm struggling to compute this. Can anyone help?

Comment: First, the square needs to be inside the expectation. Second, it’s $\alpha^2$ and not $\alpha$. Third, $S_n-S$ is an average of $n$ independent rv with null expectation so $E(|S_n-S|^2)=n^{-1}V(S_1)$.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, $U_k$ is $X_k$, I've edited it above, sorry